# sql select in relation many-to-many not works as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, many-to-many

i have the following tables in relation many-to-many:

```
table product:
prd_cod (pk)
cat_cod (fk)
prd_nome 

table description_characteristic:
prd_cod(fk)
id_characteristic(fk)
description

table characteristic:
id_characteristic(pk)
name
```

we suppose that the cat_cod will be 1, I would like to show data like this:

I have done this select below to solve my problem:

```
select p.prd_cod,p.prd_name,c.name_characteristic,dc.description
from product p,description_characteristic dc, characteristic c
where p.prd_cod = dc.prd_cod and
dc.id_ccharacteristic = c.id_characteristic and
p.cat_cod = 1
```

**but the data were shown this way:**

```
Prd_cod  Prd_name   name_characteristic  descript  
  1          pen        Color            pink      
  1          Pen        manufacturer     kingston  
  1          Pen        type                 brush
  1          Pen        weight               0.020
```

**I want to show the result this way:**

```
Prd_cod  Prd_name   name_characteristic  descript  name_characteristic  descript
  1          pen        Color            pink      type                 brush
  2          Pen-drive  manufacturer     kingston  weight               0.020
```

I can not do a select to solve this
please i need help
Thank you all

Comment: The act of selecting the appropriate data, and displaying it in some specific format, are two separate steps. Your goal should not be to produce that output with a SQL query. Defining your question like this, the answer is ambiguous; what would you do if a product had 1 or 3 related descriptions instead of 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select VALUES YOU WANT
FROM CATEGORIES
LEFT JOIN product ON
product.cat_cod=CATEGORIES.cat_cod
LEFT JOIN description_characteristic ON
product.prd_cod = description_characteristic.prd_cod
LEFT JOIN characteristic ON
description_characteristic.id_characteristic=characteristic.id_characteristic
WHERE CATEGORIES.cat_cod = "1";
```

You will need to put tablename.column to select fields which exist in more than one table.

(I assumed your categories table was called CATEGORIES)

Comment: I believe OP is looking for a dynamic pivot for an unknown number of characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

This query should resolve your problem, it will come in the same column....

```
select 
    p.prd_cod
    , p.prd_name 
    , GROUP_CONCAT(c.name,dc.description) cd_list
from 
    product p
    ,description_characteristic dc
    ,characteristic c
where 
    p.prd_cod = dc.prd_cod and
    dc.id_characteristic = c.id_characteristic and
    p.cat_cod = 1
```